# How to disable creation of Document root

Tags: xsd, eclipse-emf

I am using EMF with an XSD generated ecore. Now I've got the propblem, that the generated file isn't valid.
There are 2 Reasons:

1. There is a DocumentRoot element inserted
2. The attributes have the wrong capitalization.

The thing is: It is not a problem of the model, it is Propblem of the saving process (since in the EMF generated editor the output is correct.

First the correct result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model:widgetspecification xmlns:model="http://test.com/model" Description="DESC" Name="NAME">
  <model:Property Name="PROP1"/>
  <model:Property Name="PROP2/>
</model:widgetspecification>
```

The actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<model:DocumentRoot xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:model="http://test.com/model">
  <widgetspecification description="DESC" name="NAME">
    <property name="PROP1"/>
    <property name="PROP2"/>
  </widgetspecification>
</model:DocumentRoot>
```

And finally the save procedure (just output to sysout)

```
Resource resource = new XMIResourceImpl();
resource.getContents().add(modelRoot);
resource.save(System.out, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

Sadly I couldn't find any relevant differences in the saving routines (although of course the EMF generated code is a lot more complicated) - I guess I may have missed s.th. but I still haven't found anything).
Also interesting is the fact, that the EMF generated file is UTF-8, but I can't find any reference where this option is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XMLResource` instead of `XMIResource` and set `OPTION_EXTENDED_META_DATA` to true.

```
XMLResource resource = new XMLResourceImpl();
resource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
resource.getContents().add(modelRoot);
Map<Object, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put(XMLResource.OPTION_EXTENDED_META_DATA, true);
resource.save(System.out, options);
```